# Gurobi/CVXPY Contraints to Integer Variable

Tags: gurobi, cvxpy

I have a big MILP that I want to solve. It has a vector of binary variables. I can reduce the number of variables the problem has to try out by about half. Meaning I can put half of the values to 0 by default. I have done this by adding constraints to the problem that constraint each variable I can reduce to 0.

My problem is that it does not seem to improve the performance by any means.

The part of the problem looks like this  `mx5@u` where `mx5` is a block matrix and `u` is my binary variable.

Theoretically reducing the integer variable should net huge improvements so I'm a bit confused why this is not helping at all.

Futhermore I wouldn't really know of any way to reduce the integer variable in a different way since this would mean my vector `u` would still have to be of length L and my integer variable `u_red` would have length L-L/2.

Anybody has some idea?

Comment: `Theoretically reducing the integer variable should net huge improvements so I'm a bit confused why this is not helping at all.` **Not necessarily!** The number of variables is not a good indicator of the hardness of your instance. All solvers are heavily relying on heuristics or exploiting common structures which makes performance hard to predict. It seems, the solver arrived easily at the same conclusion as you (fix to zero) when you zeroed them out a-priori.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-integer-programming